# Find the maximum value returned by a MYSQL query and store it in a variable using PHP

Tags: return-value, max

I want to store the maximum value retrieved after a SQL fetch and store it in PHP.

Problem is it does not work as it works for normal selects. the code is below;

```
               $sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(SRNO) FROM udata");
               echo $sql;
```

OUTPUT is "Resource id #6 "

Since it returns one value I tried to directly print it. But the output was unexpected.
Please help me on this.

Comment: "the output was unexpected" - wait, what would have been the **expected** output? Also, why not just `SELECT TOP 1`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(SRNO) as value FROM udata");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['value']; // or $row[0]
```

Comment: You welcome :) please mark this answer as correct for other users.

Comment: by making a click on the check left of this post and a one click on the arrow up.